# RadSideDrawer bug found that's easily reproducible

Tags: telerik, nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm using RadSideDrawer in a {N} project.

If you open and close the drawer quickly (showing just about 1-2 mm) - then all taps are ignored until the drawer is opened manually again.

I think it's a timing issue - even though closed, the control thinks it's open. This bug is also reproducible in Telerik's sample projects in the Play Store.

Any one from Telerik here??

Comment: Hey dashman - what do you mean by "taps are ignored" - are we talking generally about all the taps on the page on which the drawer was opened-closed!?

Comment: I would recommend you to post this directly to the nativescript-telerik-ui repo's issues section (https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/issues/new) with a sample project and all of the necessary step to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: All taps are ignored, except the gesture to open the drawer fully manually. Close the drawer and then everything works again. To reproduce this the key is to open/close the drawer very quickly. This bug is also in the Play Store "Examples Nativescript" app.

Answer (score 0):

Developer from the nativescript-ui team here. Thank you for reporting this issue to us. For anyone interested please follow this thread in the official *nativescript-telerik-ui-samples* github repository [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/issues/136).

The issue is related to quick interaction with the RadSideDrawer component on the Android OS, simply taping the edge of the screen reproduces the issue.